# where can i find office open xml complete reference?

Tags: .net, ms-office, openxml, openxml-sdk

i am planning to develop a server side generation of MS office files with the help of office open XML method.....
I found only less examples/reference in microsoftsite....
does any one know where can i find the complete reference....
Thanks...

following are the links i found so far

**Office Open XML SDK for Visual Studio**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/2010/03/15/open-xml-sdk-2-0-rtm-articles-videos-code-snippets-and-resources-on-msdn.aspx

**Code Snipper/Examples/Samples**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/2009/08/28/open-xml-sdk-2-0-august-ctp-and-50-open-xml-code-samples.aspx

**Open XML getting started**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/2009/05/14/open-xml-format-sdk-2-0-getting-started-best-practices.aspx

**office open xml blog main archive page**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/tags/open+xml/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the ECMA specifications here:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

You can find the ISO/IEC 29500 specifciation here:

http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=51463

or here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee908652(v=office.12).aspx